# storing database values in source control

Tags: database, database-design, version-control

We have a table in our our database that stores XSL's and XSD's that are applied to XML documents created in our application. This table is versioned in the sense that each time a change is made, a new row is created.

I'm trying to propose that we store the XSL's and XSD's as files in our Source control system instead of relying on the database to track the history. Each time a file is updated, we would deploy the new version to the database.

I don't seem to be getting much agreement on the issue. can anyone help me out with pros and cons of this approach? Perhaps I'm missing something.

Answer (score 1):

XSL and XSD files are part of the application and so ought to be kept under source control.  That's just obvious.  Even if somebody wanted to catgorise them as data they would be reference data and so - in my book at least - would need to be kept under source control.  This is because reference data is part of the application and so part of its configuration.  For instance, applications which use the database to store values for drop downs or to implement business rules need to be certain that it holds the right version of the data.

The only argument for keeping multiple versions of the files in the dtabase would be if you might need to process older versions of the XML files.  This depends on the nature of your application.  Certainly I have worked on systems where XML files / messages came from external (third party) systems, where we really had no control over the format of the messages sent.  So for a variety of reasons we needed to be able to handle incoming XML regardless of whether its structure was current or historical.  But is is in addition to storing the files in a source control repository, not instead of.